# Plan for generating external funding

Tags: application, funding, faculty-application, application-cover-letter, research-proposal

I am preparing an application for a full-time lecturer position. They asked me for a teaching statement (done), a research statement (done) and a plan for generating funding for the next three years (trying now). I am a bit confused about this and I am not sure what they actually want with this funding plan. I could, of course, name all the different grant applications that I could potentially submit, but I am convinced that they are expecting more than that.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: country? field?

Comment: UK. The field is psychology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would expect here is a (short) document where you describe how you plan to build up your lab in the next three years. Which personal grants to you plan to target? Do you have multiple options, or will you be all-in on one specific grant? Are there specific project calls or larger consortia where you could apply, and what makes you a good person to apply for them (i.e., this is a good place to brag about your network for participating in larger collaborations)? Are there other types of grants (for infrastructure, etc.) that are required or useful for the kind of work that you do? How will the different types of grants connect to form a larger research agenda?

All in all, I expect that the committee really wants to see (a) that  there are funding sources available that you can realistically apply to - ideally, these will be a combination of high-risk/high-reward calls (e.g., highly prestigious personal grants) and more conservative projects, and (b) that you are aware of the different funding sources and have a plan in mind how you will use them to build up  your group. Everybody understands that this is, at best, a declaration of intent - grants get rejected, new opportunities arise, and your research interests shift, so nobody will fault you if you, 3 years from now, have deviated greatly from this plan.